# Is there a way to uniquely identify a smart contract other than by its address?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I would like to know if there is a way different than the contract adress to identify a smart contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address is the only truly unique identifier for a contract, because the same source code (bytecode) can be used to deploy multiple instances of the contract. You could of course try to analyze the contract transactions to decide whether it *looks like* the contract you are looking for, but you can never be sure without checking the address.

Note that this is only true inside one blockchain (network): a different blockchain (for example a testnet) may have the same bytecode in the same address.